# Jar error: could not find or failed to load main class

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have built a simple GUI that takes in unorganized HTML code and organizes it...now that I have it working finally I need to learn how to distribute it. I managed to create my .jar file but when I try to run it I get "Error: could not find or failed to load main class HTMLFormatter.class"

Here's what I did:

First, I went to my "bin" folder in my project directory and copied all the applicable class files into another separate folder (cause i didn't want to accidentally mess up my original class files). In that separate folder I also created manifest.txt which contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: HTMLFormatter.class
Class-Path: .
```

Then I ran this command from that directory:

```
jar cfm HTMLFormatter.jar manifest.txt ./*.class
```

This created the JAR just fine, I used winrar to peek inside and it contained all the proper class files and the manifest was in META-INF directory. Then I tried to run it, first by double clicking, though I'm not even sure if that is SUPPOSED to work...Then I tried running it via command line using this command:

```
java -jar HTMLFormatter.jar
```

Which is when I got the error message. Then I read a post from this site that implied windows sometimes uses javaw instead... so i used the same command above with javaw and it didn't give me an error, but it still didn't produce my GUI.

So, what am I missing? also when I finally figure this out, should I be able to just double-click the jar file? (windows 8.1 64bit in case it matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, still not sure why the way I was doing it didn't work, but I did get it to work via Eclipse now. Here's what I did for others' future reference:

1. in Eclipse: File > export
2. Expand "Java" section, select "Runnable JAR File", click next
3. for "launch configuration" choose your class and project, they are listed in this format: "class name - project name"
4. Click "Browse" to select your export destination (where you want the JAR file placed)
5. the section titled "Library handling" I don't fully understand, but the default option (top one) worked for me.
6. Finish.
7. test it by double-clicking on it

Hope this helps others!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your main class definition is wrong. It should be `Main-Class: com.my.example.HTMLFormatter`

Comment: I have seen this suggestion before and from what I understand the "com.my.example" part is the package right? I read that it isn't necessary but highly recommended, so I'm definitely down to try that but I don't really understand the concept of what a package is or how to use one appropriately... Sorry, I am still a student!